# KnockoutJS mappings, JSON from WebAPI

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I am able to bind JSON returned from .net WebAPI to a knockout viewmodel using the following code.

```
function viewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.temps = ko.observableArray([]);
}

$(function () { 
    var model = new viewModel();

    $.get('../api/Temp/', function (data) { 
        model.temps(data);
    });

    ko.applyBindings(model);       

});
```

When  I try to use [Ryan Niemeyer 's mapping example](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html) I am getting null when using `ko.utils.parseJson` on my returned Json and when I try to use the `ko.utils.arrayMap` directly I am getting undefined.

I am also struggling to take the get request into a separate function if I try the following, my data binding stops working

```
function dataFromServer() {
    $.get('../api/Temp/', function (data) { 
        return data;
    });
}

$(function () { 
    var model = new viewModel();
    var data = dataFromServer();
    model.temps(data);

    ko.applyBindings(model);       

});
```

Returned JSON from server :

```
[{"Id":1,"Name":"Test1","TypeId":100,"Temp":21.0,"Peak":true},{"Id":2,"Name":"Test2","TypeId":100,"Temp":21.0,"Peak":true},{"Id":3,"Name":"Test3","TypeId":101,"Temp":21.0,"Peak":true}]
```

Comment: Could you please add JSON returned from the server.

Comment: You are not assigning anything the `data` variable right? It's not even defined.

Comment: I was in my code, must have lost in re-writing for the question. I've assigned it to a variable now, have tried a few variations of this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AJAX call is asynchronous, so it will not return your data immediately from your function here:

```
$.get('../api/Temp/', function (data) { 
        return data;
    });
```

You might want to pass the observable/observableArray that you want to write the result to into your function like:

```
function dataFromServer(temps) {
    $.get('../api/Temp/', function (data) { 
        return temps(data);
    });
}
```

Then call it like:

```
var model = new viewModel();
dataFromServer(model.temps);
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan, hoped you would answer.  In terms of doing the manual mapping, should I do this in the function with the get request or somewhere else?

Comment: I personally try to keep my AJAX calls segregated from my view model and try to deal with plain JS objects on that side.  Then, on the view model side, I use a constructor function that takes in the plain data and builds it with appropriate observables.  There are many ways to do it, but here is one sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Qx4U7/.  In this case, you can test the ViewModel without worrying about AJAX requests and/or swap out the "DataClient" with one that deals with static data.